# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in React Native when running tests

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, ts-jest, detox

I have implemented detox for my react native app.
I created `dashboard.test.tsx` to run my first tests. Below you can see a sample test I wrote in that file.

```
import { device } from 'detox';
import { Dashboard } from '../app/screens/Dashboard';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react-native';


describe('First tests', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await device.launchApp({ newInstance: true, permissions: { notifications: 'YES' } });
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
    
   
  it('should be able to test dasboard screen', async () => {
      render(<Dashboard/>);
   
});
```

When I try to run the test file I get the below error.

```
(0, react_native_1.render)(<Dashboard_1.Dashboard />);
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1598:14)
```

This is my `jest.config.js` file inside e2e folder

```
/** @type {import('@jest/types').Config.InitialOptions} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
  rootDir: '..',
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>/e2e/**/*.test.tsx'],
  testTimeout: 120000,
  maxWorkers: 1,
  globalSetup: 'detox/runners/jest/globalSetup',
  globalTeardown: 'detox/runners/jest/globalTeardown',
  reporters: ['detox/runners/jest/reporter'],
  testEnvironment: 'detox/runners/jest/testEnvironment',
  verbose: true,
};
```

This is the `jest.config.js` file in the root folder

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node']
};
```

React-native: 0.64.2
detox: 20.1.2
jest: 29.4.1

Anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65788095/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-on-shallow-render-with-enzyme-and-jest-in-reac

Comment: thanks but, it didn't work for me